# How to skip port is use of ng serve and use automatically the default port +1

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I set in `angular.json` the default port to 8080. But I like to start multiple projects. They all have the same default port like this

```
...
"serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "port": 8080
          },
...
```

Using `ng serve` starts the project like expected in localhost:8080. But if I start another project with `ng serve` I get the answer `Port is already in use. Would you like to use a different port? (Y/n)` .
How can I skip automatically this message? And how can I achieve that the second project starts automatically in `localhost:8081`, the third project in `localhost:8082` and so on? The pattern should be last used port plus one. I am not looking for a solution like adding manually `ng serve --port 8081`.

Comment: you can start another project with this command: `ng serve --port=5000`   First project will run on 4200 and 2nd project will start at 5000.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you want to have multiple apps access from the same base url example.com/app1,example.com/app2, it that correct?
You can do that by having each app in a library and by creating a main application to route from.

I have created an example for you.You can see the diff here: https://github.com/nrwl/nx-examples/commit/fe2bed81e699bc4c36cf4f751305e72471a54083
You can run the app by running

Comment: No, I need it for my local environment

Comment: You can use in your local environment

Comment: No, the apps are totally separate and completely different projects. It is impossible to have a main application

Answer (score 0):

Change port number in angular.json for every project. then start project with ng serve --project=projectA. You can't run multiple projects at the same time with ng CLI.

If you are looking for more robust way to run your applications try switching to nrwl. `https://nx.dev/latest/angular/cli/run-many`

Comment: Changing in angular.json the port is of course a good solution, but I prefer using for each projet a default port and only in cause of working on two project (e.g. for comparing them in browser) an other port. So I need a solution, which is more automated and do not needs manual work. And a solution which do not make me think about port.